# Array Pointer not returning from C++ function

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following code to initialize an array, which works:

```
int main() {
    int particle_count = 10000;

    MyRNG my_rng = MyRNG(0.0,1.0);

    Particle simulation_particles[particle_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < particle_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            simulation_particles[i].assign(j,my_rng.next());
        }
    }
```

However, when I try to put the for loops in functions, all particles get set to the same values:

```
void initialize_particle(Particle * p,MyRNG rgen)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        float value = rgen.next();
        p->assign(i,value);
    }
}
void initialize_simulation_particles(int size,Particle * simulation_particles,MyRNG rgen)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        initialize_particle(&simulation_particles[i],rgen);
    }
}


int main() {
    int particle_count = 10000;

    MyRNG my_rng = MyRNG(0.0,1.0);

    Particle simulation_particles[particle_count];
    initialize_simulation_particles(particle_count,simulation_particles,my_rng);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `void initialize_simulation_particles(int size,Particle * simulation_particles, MyRNG rgen)` you take `rgen` by value. That means you get a copy of the random generator `my_rng` from `main`. Since it is a pseudo random number generator that produces the same numbers on a given state and you copy the same state to the function every time it produces the same number every time. The solution is to pass it by reference in `initialize_simulation_particles` and `initialize_particle` using `MyRNG &rgen` so that the state of `my_rng` progresses and therefore produces different numbers for each particle.

Comment: thank  you. I was on the totally wrong track, thinking I was making a mistake w.r.t. scope and the array pointers (started C++ Wednesday).